# How to Return All Rows in a Table of Azure Mobile Service .Net Backend

Tags: xamarin, azure-mobile-services

How can I fetch all Rows of a Table in Azure Mobile Services .Net Backend with no Where clause. Here is my attempt and it is not working. Its saying undefined member.

```
public async Task<List<Customer>> FetchAllCustomers()
       {
           var allCustomers = new List<Customer>();
           try
           {
               var list = await _customerTable.ToListAsync();
               foreach (var customer in list)
               {
                   allCustomers.Add(customer);
               }
           }
           catch (Exception e)
           {
               Log.Info(Tag, "Error fetching Customers" + e.Message);
           }

           return allCustomers;
}
```

How can I re-write this simple method to fetch all customers in a Customer table in Azure Service. I am calling from a Xamarin.Android client and I have successfully added items to this table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Carlos have already answered a similar question here [Azure Mobile Service query doesn't return all the rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14088469/azure-mobile-service-query-doesnt-return-all-the-rows?rq=1)

I added new field called Active so I can apply Where(active = Customer.Active);

The query now looks like this

```
var list = await _customerTable.Take(100).Where(active => Customer.Active).ToListAsync();
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the problem of only getting 50 records returned from my Azure table but I knew there were more. I used the following with Xamarin C# to query for the total row count of the table then use the row count to get all records if under 1000 else use 1000. Note that the count query uses Take(0) so that no records are returned, only the total row count.

The  use of IQueryResultEnumerable came from Anzur Patel ITotalCountProvider casting error Xamarin forum.

[Azure Mobile Service query doesn't return all the rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14088469/azure-mobile-service-query-doesnt-return-all-the-rows?rq=1)  provided the reason for only getting 50 records and why I use the max of 1000 if total row count exceeds 1000.

[How to get the row count from an azure database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15616486/how-to-get-the-row-count-from-an-azure-database)  provided the method of using includeTotalCount().

```
// query table to include the total row count
var tableRowCount = (await _syncRecordTable.Take(0)
                   .Where (SyncRec => SyncRec.userid == sOwnerUniquCode )   
                   .IncludeTotalCount()
                   .ToEnumerableAsync());

// get the row count
long tCount = ((IQueryResultEnumerable<syncrecords>)tableRowCount).TotalCount;


// convert long to int by casting
int iCount = (int) tCount;

if (iCount < 1000) {
    // get all records from the table
_listCloudSyncRec = (await _syncRecordTable.Take(iCount)
        .Where (SyncRec => SyncRec.userid == sOwnerUniquCode)
        .ToListAsync ());
}else {
_listCloudSyncRec = (await _syncRecordTable.Take(1000)
        .Where (SyncRec => SyncRec.userid == sOwnerUniquCode )
        .ToListAsync ());
}
```