# Xamarin Forms pull async on node backend fails if getting over 50 rows

Tags: c#, node.js, xamarin.forms

When running a PullAsync on a Node.JS back-end from a Xamarin Forms cross platform app, the call is successful if the table has up to 50 rows.

```
 public async Task Sync<T>()
        {
            if (!CrossConnectivity.Current.IsConnected) { return; }
            var table = Client.GetSyncTable<T>();

            if (Client.SyncContext.IsInitialized)
            {
                await table.PullAsync(null, table.CreateQuery());
            }
        }
```

The PullAsync seems to add Skip(0) and Take(50).
If I make a call to a table with more than 50, even though I have specified `table.maxTop = 100;` in the node table definition, the app errors with

```
Error:An error occurred while sending the request
```

while the innerException is

```
{System.Net.WebException: Error: ConnectFailure (Connection timed out) ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: Connection timed out.....
```

but I think this is due to an error on the node side where I added the maxTop = 100.
Is there anything obvious Im missing that I need to retrieve more than 50 rows at a time?

I read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14088469/azure-mobile-service-query-doesnt-return-all-the-rows) which details something similar, querying an azure table, but I want to do this when using PullAsync.

UPDATE:

Ok, what I think is happening is this,

if I have up to 50 rows, its all fine.

More than 50 and I think the 1st query will run with skip(0), take(50).

It will run again with skip(50) take (50), and do this each time incrementing the skip total until there are no more rows to process.

It seems that, although this is how it should behave, it's not actually succeeding after the 1st 50

Comment: What type is `Client`?

Comment: Another question is: why is it taking so long?

Comment: client is MobileServiceClient

Comment: @Stefan - when returning 50 it is quick, if over 50 it hangs but I think it's possibly to do with the maxTop I added to the table def in node

Comment: Yes possibly, is there any documentation on what it does, `maxTop`?

Comment: The thing is; the difference between 50 and 100 isn't that much; so it's "suspicious".

Comment: just updated the post after running a few more tests

Comment: Have you seen this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31528351/imobileserviceclient-pullasync-deadlock-when-trying-to-sync-with-azure-mobile-se?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer.

Replacing the line

```
await table.PullAsync(null, table.CreateQuery());
```

with

```
        var query = table.CreateQuery().Skip(0).Take(1000);
        var pullOptions = new PullOptions() { MaxPageSize = 5000 };
        await table.PullAsync(null, query, pullOptions);
```

did the trick